# how to use python inside SQL server 2014

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have some experience with SQL and python.

In one of my SQL stored procedures I want to use some python code block and some functions of python numpy.

What is the best way to do it.SQL server version is 2014.

Comment: This is way to broad. Please ask a specific question. Also, python was introduced in sql server 2016.

Comment: I want to use correlation function from python inside my SQL code because SQL don't have one of this kind.

Comment: You should look into clr. You can incorporate python in c# code, and use that in sql.

Comment: Along with R, Python [machine learning services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/machine-learning-services-tutorials) was introduced in SQL Server 2016 where you can run code directly in a stored proc. Otherwise, import stored proc resultset data into Python and run needed operation.

Answer (score 0):

First install the MySQL connector for python from the MySQL website and then import the `mysql.connector` module and initialize a variable to a `mysql.connector.connect` object and use cursors to modify and query data. Look at the documentation for more help.

If you don't have problem with no networking capabilities and less concurrency use sqlite, it is better than MySQL in these cases.

Comment: The author asked for SQL Server specifically - this answer is for MySQL only and cannot be adjusted to fit SQL Server use cases.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5036/installing-python-and-running-python-scripts-from-sql-server-ssms/) explains a rather tortuous means of calling Python routines via xp_cmdshell, for versions of SQL Server prior to the introduction of the sp_execute_external_script command in SQL Server 2016. I haven't tried it yet but it appears to be a rather difficult process. I don't believe the author listed the editions he verified the workaround on either. Good luck.